# Django: Order of imports means only one views.py files is accessable

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm just working through the [DjangoBook Chapter7 tutorial](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) on creating forms.

My issue is that I can only import one `views.py` file from either my `books` or `contact` directories. As a result I am only able to see the pages created by whichever views.py file is imported at the time.

I believe I need someway of differentiating between the two directories so that Django does not get confused (due to my likely bad implementation). I have also included an image of my project directory which might be useful to understand the problem.

**Contact import working**

```
from mysite.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead, display_meta
from contact import views
#from books import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...

    #url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
    #url(r'^search/$', views.search),    

    url(r'^contact_form/$', views.contact), 
)
```

**Books import working**

```
from mysite.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead, display_meta
#from contact import views
from books import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....

    url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search),    

   #url(r'^contact_form/$', views.contact), 
)
```

**My Project structure. I am working in Eclipse with Pydev.**

[image]

**Both contact and books import implemented give the below error**

```
AttributeError at /search/

'module' object has no attribute 'search_form'
```

Any help is as always much appreciated.

Comment: An alternative to @dimamobile's answer would be to just do `import books` and `import contact`, and then access what you need with `books.views.search_form` and `contact.views.contact` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an `as` statement:

```
from contact import views as contact_views
from books import views as books_views
```

and the call view:

```
url(r'^search-form/$', books_views.search_form),
url(r'^search/$', books_views.search),
url(r'^contact_form/$', contact_views.contact),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the urls.py in your application, as detailed in [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/).

In your *application directory* create a `urls.py`,

```
contact
   - __init__.py
   - views.py
   - models.py
   - urls.py
books
   - __init__.py
   - views.py
   - models.py
   - urls.py
```

In book/urls.py, add the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import search, search_form

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'search-form/$', search_form, name='search_form'),
)
```

Then in your main `urls.py`, add the following:

```
url(r'^books/', include('book.urls')),
```

Please go through the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) as the django book website is out dated.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not making a separate 'contact' application as per chapter 7 "Our personal preference would be to create a separate directory, contact, at the same level in the directory tree as books. This would contain an empty __init__.py and views.py.)" I have went through the official tutorial but did not get enough from it so i am using this book as well. I think your solution is best for creating multiple applications inside one project, i will keep it in mind for the future.